# insert data into different object using one submit button

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have to insert data into two objects via visualforce page. One object is  custom and another object is user.

How to insert data into two different objects through visualforce page.

Answer (score 2):

In general, by using a custom controller or a controller extension.

You'd then adjust your `save()` method to perform 2 DML operations. `User`, however, is a *setup object* and we can't perform DML on both a setup object and a non-setup object in the same transaction (you'll get a `MIXED_DML_EXCEPTION` if you try that).

To avoid the mixed DML error, one of your DML operations needs to happen in another execution context. I.e. you need to use an `@future` method or enqueue a `Queueable` class to do this.

It's impossible to give you more specific advice when you provide so little detail.